# Generating .html file from template engine

Tags: html, node.js, templates

My aim is to create some html files (about 30, preferably via CLI) that are identical except for some arbitrary variables to be replaced in the url of links and scripts sources.

I wish I could automate the file creation process but I'm still struggling with the structure.

My first idea was to use Mustache or Handlebars and save the HTML output to file. It's possible with those tools? Are there any more suitable tools or methods?

Ideal for me would be to create files via node and CLI

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you know programming, i.e. python, create a script for the job. Run the program from cli with parameters or create a configuration file for each .html and load the configuration file in the python script.

Comment: Python was my first choice, I wanted to understand if there were tools to do the same thing rather than writing the code for the compilation myself...